# Help shifting left in align

Tags: math-mode, align, arrays

So I have this problem in my equation, that the bottom equation keeps shifting right even though I need it to be aligned at the 'left side'.
Can someone one help?

```
\begin{align}
 P(y=m\vert x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\dfrac{exp(\sum_{r=m}^{M-1} [\alpha_r-\beta'x ])}{1+\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} [exp(\sum_{r=q}^{M-1} [\alpha_r-\beta'x ])]} & \text{if} \ 1 \leq m < M-1, \\
\\
1-\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} P(y=q \vert x) & \text{if} \ m=M
\end{array} \right. 
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: For readability it might be an idea to use `\mid` (or some other user defined macro) instead of `\vert` in the last line of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `cases` or, better, `dcases*` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 P(y=m\mid x)=
\begin{dcases*}
\frac{\displaystyle \exp\biggl(\,\sum_{r=m}^{M-1} [\alpha_r-\beta'x ]\biggr)}
     {\displaystyle 1+\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} \biggl[\exp\biggl(\,\sum_{r=q}^{M-1}
       [\alpha_r-\beta'x ]\biggr)\biggr]}
 & if $1 \leq m < M-1$, \\[2ex]
1-\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} P(y=q \mid x) & if $m=M$
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

With `dcases*` the first part is typeset in display style, so fractions are big; I also added `\displaystyle` in the fraction terms, for uniformity and to save horizontal space.

A few points to note:

1. use `equation`, not `align`, for a single equation;
2. use `\mid`, not `\vert` (for the spacing);
3. use `\exp`, not `exp`;
4. the big parentheses in front of the summation needs some small additional space, in order not to clash with the limits, which is achieved with `\,`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the arguments `{rl}` in the array definition. It moves right the first column. Also cases is used more often in such equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
P(y=m\vert x)=\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{ll} \dfrac{exp(\sum_{r=m}^{M-1} [\alpha_r-\beta'x ])}{1+\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} [exp(\sum_{r=q}^{M-1} [\alpha_r-\beta'x ])]} & \text{if} \ 1 \leq m < M-1, \\
1-\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} P(y=q \vert x) & \text{if} \ m=M\\ \end{array} 
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

Also I removed align since cases already takes care... But also array doesnt needed anymore so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
P(y=m\vert x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{exp(\sum_{r=m}^{M-1} [\alpha_r-\beta'x ])}{1+\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} [exp(\sum_{r=q}^{M-1} [\alpha_r-\beta'x ])]} & \text{if} \ 1 \leq m < M-1, \\
1-\sum_{q=1}^{M-1} P(y=q \vert x) & \text{if} \ m=M\\ 
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

Welcome!

[image]

Comment: could use a little vertical skip between the two equations, but that's personal flavor, I reckon.

Comment: You are right... I think it is not a matter of taste but a must in such cases.. Anyway... I just tried to show the way.. But your comment is still usefull